# Webpack keeps compiling node modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm currently transitioning from webpack `v1.13.2` to `2.6.1` and i've followed the Migr[ating from v1 to v2](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) docs but for some reason I can't find webpack keeps compiling node modules (while I've excluded the folder).

Would love some help as currently it's killing me with errors and a very slow (40s) build time which was previously 4.8s on average. Also the bundle size went up from 4.1mb to 10.1mb.

**Folder structure**

- node_modules
- webpack.config.js
- app (aka src)
- build (aka dist)
- export

**My super simple `webpack.config.js` file**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'js'),

    entry: {
        bundle: 'index.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join('app', 'js'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'js'),
        filename: 'react.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'react.js.map'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: [
                    '/(node_modules)/',
                    '/(bower_components)/'
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        'babel-preset-react',
                        'babel-preset-es2015',
                        'babel-preset-stage-0'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Example of an error (you can see it is from compiling `react-dropzone`)**

```
ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/wizer_sorted/dashboard/~/react-dropzone/dist/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wizer_sorted\\dashboard\\node_modules\\react-dropzone\\.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "C:\\xampp
\\htdocs\\wizer_sorted\\dashboard\\node_modules\\react-dropzone"
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:180:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:48:20)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer_sorted\dashboard\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:163:20)
 @ ./components/molecules/Upload/index.js 23:21-46
 @ ./components \.\/(atoms|molecules|organisms)\/[^\/]+\/index\.js
 @ ./components/index.js
 @ ./routing/app.js
 @ ./routing/routes.js
 @ ./index.js
```

**Update 1**

After implementing the correct `Rules.exclude` thanks to @AndrewLi the build time went down to about 15 seconds however the build size remained the same and I can still see that stuff that shouldn't be in there is. See screenshot below.
[image]

**Update 2**

I was comparing `devtool: 'eval'` with `devtoo: 'cheap-eval-source-map'`. So actually the build size is back to normal. The only thing that keeps unchanged is the build speed which still has over **15 seconds** compared to the **5 seconds** of webpack `v1.13.2`.

Comment: Probably not relevant in terms of build speed, but a neater config would declare a straight `Rules.include` path instead of a set of `Rules.exclude`.

Comment: @toomuchdesign this was suggested by somebody who deleted his / her answer so it is now the case in my config :) Thanks anyway!